# How to center a Table or a List horizontally in a FlowDocument?

Tags: wpf, xaml, flowdocument

Below is sample code from a default WPF application's MainWindow.xaml. First and last 'Block's in the document are paragraphs and the middle one is a table. Table always appear at the left edge of its column and the area to the right of the table is blank. I would like to center the table in this space.

I have tried putting the table inside a 'Section', a 'Paragraph' etc, but didn't have any luck. A Floater inside a paragraph works, but then the table flow into the next paragraph. Probably I can do this by using two empty columns on the left and right with some way to calculate their widths dynamically, but that looks overkill.

Thanks
Jeevaka

```
<Window x:Class="FlowDocument.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="700" Width="700">
    <FlowDocumentPageViewer>
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph FontSize="24">Moons of Saturn</Paragraph>
            <Paragraph>The moons of Saturn are numerous and diverse, ranging from tiny moonlets less than 1 kilometre across, to the enormous Titan, which is larger than the planet Mercury. Saturn has 62 moons with confirmed orbits, fifty-three of which have names, and only thirteen of which have diameters larger than 50 kilometres. Saturn has seven moons that are large enough to become spherical, and dense rings with complex orbital motions of their own. Particularly notable among Saturn's moons are Titan, the second largest moon in the Solar System, with a nitrogen-rich Earth-like atmosphere and a landscape including hydrocarbon lakes and dry river networks, and Enceladus, which emits jets of gas and dust and may harbor liquid water under its south pole region.</Paragraph>
            <Table TextAlignment="Right" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="Black">
                <Table.Columns>
                    <TableColumn Width="100" ></TableColumn>
                    <TableColumn Width="100"></TableColumn>
                </Table.Columns>
                <TableRowGroup>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell Background="White" Padding="5">
                            <Paragraph>Name</Paragraph>
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell Background="White" Padding="5">
                            <Paragraph>Diameter</Paragraph>
                        </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell Background="White" Padding="5">
                            <Paragraph>Mimas</Paragraph>
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell Background="White" Padding="5">
                            <Paragraph>396</Paragraph>
                        </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell Background="White" Padding="5">
                            <Paragraph>Enceladus</Paragraph>
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell Background="White" Padding="5">
                            <Paragraph>504</Paragraph>
                        </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell Background="White" Padding="5">
                            <Paragraph>Tethys</Paragraph>
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell Background="White" Padding="5">
                            <Paragraph>1062</Paragraph>
                        </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableRowGroup>
            </Table>
            <Paragraph>Twenty-four of Saturn's moons are regular satellites; they have prograde orbits not greatly inclined to Saturn's equatorial plane. They include the seven major satellites, four small moons which exist in a Trojan orbit with larger moons, two mutually co-orbital moons and two moons which act as shepherds of Saturn's F Ring. Two other known regular satellites orbit within gaps in Saturn's rings. The relatively large Hyperion is locked in a resonance with Titan. The remaining regular moons orbit near the outer edge of the A Ring, within G Ring and between the major moons Mimas and Enceladus. The regular satellites are traditionally named after Titans and Titanesses or other figures associated with the mythological Saturn.</Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </FlowDocumentPageViewer>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a WPF element attribute called `HorizontalAlignment` you would want to surround the element of interest within a container Like a grid or border and set the attribute to `Center` WPF does the rest of the magic.